# Drupal 8 Webform URL alias with parameters

Tags: webforms

On the URL PATH SETTINGS,  I want to define the Webform URL alias to include a variable parameter e.g. /my-web-form-url/{id}
Is this possible? I want to pass this 'id' as a hidden value in the form.

Comment: This solution was very simple and worked for me: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/278757/67688

Answer (score 2):

You would need to write some custom code to support custom URL parameters. (see [How to (truly) alter a URL in Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238921/how-to-truly-alter-a-url-in-drupal-8))

You could easily pass the 'id' as a query string parameter, which is supported as long as you enable 'Allow elements to be populated using query string parameters.' under a Webform's > Settings > Form Behaviors.