# How to pass dynamic parameters through a local action button?

Tags: 8, uri, domain-access

I created a [local action](https://www.drupal.org/node/2133247) button with the following in *my_module.links.action.yml*:

```
my_module.content.action:
  route_name: node.add_page
  title: 'My action'
  deriver: 'Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Derivative\ContentByDomainLocalActions'
  appears_on:
    - view.affiliated_content.page_1
```

Then, the local action button appears in the page `admin/content/domain-content/firstdomain_local`

I'd like use the argument `firstdomain_local` from this URL path to pass it in my local action button.

So, I retrieve the param from `\Drupal::routeMatch()` in `getDerivativeDefinitions`, like in [this tutorial](https://www.webomelette.com/dynamic-menu-links-drupal-8-plugin-derivatives):

```
class CustomLocalActions extends DeriverBase {
  public function getDerivativeDefinitions($base_plugin_definition) {
    $this->derivatives['example.action_id'] = $base_plugin_definition;
    $this->derivatives['example.action_id']['title'] = "Add content";
    $domain = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('arg_0');
    $this->derivatives['example.action_id']['route_parameters'] = [
      'domain' => $domain
    ];
    return $this->derivatives;
  }
}
```

But the param of the local action button is only updated after I clear the cache. I have to clear the cache each time I use different parameter value in the URL.

**What's the correct way to pass dynamically this argument?**

Comment: Are you serving the same URL from different (sub-) domains (...and want different content [action links] per domain)? In that case you'll need a custom cache context for domains

Comment: No, it's always the same domain (for administration). I just need to retrieve the param from the URL path.

Answer (score 3):

Local actions and local tasks are quite similar, so looking at the [Customising local task behavior](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-local-tasks) I've managed to pass in dynamic route parameters to my local actions by specifying the ***class*** parameter (MyClassName) in my_module.links.action.yml and overriding the LocalActionDefault::getRouteParameters() method in that class. Only one initial cache rebuild was required.

```
use Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalActionDefault;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

class MyClassName extends LocalActionDefault {

  public function getRouteParameters(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    return array(
      'my_local_action_parameter' => $route_match->getParameter('existing_parameter_from_route')
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Cheers!

Comment: I'd also override `getCacheMaxAge()` to return zero to avoid caching it.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a [cache issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2497457), awaiting an official fix, I solved it by rebuilding actions on the page in question:

```
function my_module_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'view.affiliated_content.page_1') {
    \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.local_action')->clearCachedDefinitions();
  }
}
```